# How to create trapezoid kind of tab in css

Tags: css

[image]

I am trying to create those tabs singal use and bulk use. How to do it in css. It is like Trapezoid not exactly as the corners are rounded.
..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```css
    .container-full {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
        background: #fff;
        color: rgb(2, 2, 2);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .row {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .top-header {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .top-header img {
        height: 83vh;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .header-wrap {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .logo {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 17px;
    }
    .header-content {
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
    .header-content h1, p {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .header-content h1 {
        font-weight: 900;
        font-size: 38px;
    }
    .main-btn {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 20px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 30px;
        padding: 10px 40px 8px 40px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.2s linear;
        color: #000;
    }
    .main-btn:hover {
        background: #c86bd6;
    }
    .btn-text {
        color: #f1020d;
    }
    .content-inner {
        padding-left: 25px;
    }
    /* CODE EXAMPLE */
    .code-eg-container {
        padding-right: 0px;
    }
    .code-eg-inner {
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        height: 410px;
        background: #22015473;
        padding: 13px;
    }
    .code-eg-header {
        display: block;
    }
    .code-eg-header a {
        display: inline-block;
        color: #fff;
        margin-right: 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .tab-content {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .tab-pane {
        background: rgba(108,6,166,0.4);
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(108,6,166,0.7) 6%, rgba(25,1,153,0.6) 100%);
        border: 0;
    }
    pre {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    li {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .nav-pills li a {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 7px 21px 6px 21px;;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: #61bc44;
    line-height: normal;
    border: 0 !important;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    .code-eg-header .nav-pills li.active a {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: #61bc44 !important;
    line-height: normal;
    border: 0 !important;
    }
    /* END */

    /* MEDIA */
    @media only screen and (max-width:991px) {
        .code-eg-container {
            padding-left: 0px;
            margin-top: 25px;
        }
        .code-eg-inner {
            border-radius: 0;
        }
    }

.shape {
    border-bottom: 50px solid #555;
 border-left: 25px solid transparent;
 border-right: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class="container-full">
      <div class="top-header" style="border: 1px solid red;">
      </div>
      <div class="header-wrap">

        <div class="row header-content">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="content-inner">
              <p>
    sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsf
              </p>
              <a class="main-btn">Let's Try <span class="btn-text">It's Free</span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 code-eg-container">
                <ul>
  <li><a class="shape">dsdssdds</a></li>
    <li><a class="shape">sssdds</a></li>
</ul>

                <div class="code-eg-inner">

                  <div class="code-eg-header">
                    <ul class="nav-pills">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#phpsample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">PHP</a></li>
                        <li class=""> <a href="#curlsample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Curl</a></li>
                        <li class=""> <a href="#pythonsample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Python</a></li>
                        <li class=""> <a href="#rubysample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Ruby</a></li>
                        <li class=""> <a href="#javasample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Java</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix" ></div>
                  
                  <div class="code tab-content">
                      <pre id="phpsample" class="tab-pane active">
    $email = "test@example.com";
    $url = https://lesdsdsddsdssddsssssssssdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssshub.com/api/verifyEmail?email=$email 
    $key = "&lt;API Key&gt;";
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->get($url, 
      array(
      'headers'=> Bearer $key
      )
      );
      echo json_decode($response->getBody());
                      
                      

                      </pre>
                      <pre id="curlsample" class="tab-pane">
    curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
    https://leb.com/api/verifyEmail?email=test@example.com
                      
                      
                      
                      
                      
                      
                      
                      




    </pre>
    <pre id="pythonsample" class="tab-pane">
    curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
    https://leb.com/api/verifyEmdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddail?email=test@example.com
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
            


    </pre>
    <pre id="rubysample" class="tab-pane">
    curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
    https://lesdddddddddddddddddddddb.com/api/verifyEmail?email=test@example.com
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                


    </pre>
    <pre id="javasample" class="tab-pane">
    curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
    https://ldsfdsfsdfsdfsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssb.com/api/verifyEmail?email=test@example.com
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
      
     </pre>
                      </div>

          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have several options, but it depends on your needs.

- Do you need to keep the gradient?
- Do you need different lengths of text?

One simple way is using `:before` & `:after` pseudo-classes (but you won't easily get the gradient). We'll use CSS borders to create triangles and position them OUTSIDE an element with rounded top corners. The sharp point of the triangles is placed below the curve radius so it visually appears to start at the correct location.

This all works visually due to the element background and border colors being the same. If you change the colors its much easier to see how everything lays out.

```css
body {
 padding: 50px;
}

.tab {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  display:inline-block;
}

.tab:before, .tab:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
}

.tab:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 32px 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent aqua transparent;
  top: 6px;
  left: -20px;
}

.tab:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 32px 0 0 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent aqua;
  top: 6px;
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="tab">Tab Text</a>
```